# Select specific columns in NumPy array using colon notation

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 40000 by 60 Numpy array, and I want to sth like this:

```
mat[:,[0:13,19:23,23:31,39:59]]
```

Obviously, it does not work. Is there a smarter way to do this than concatenation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) -

```
mat[:,np.r_[0:13,19:23,23:31,39:59]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [48]: mat = np.random.rand(100,1000)

In [50]: mat[:,np.r_[0:13,19:23,23:31,39:59]].shape
Out[50]: (100, 45)

In [51]: 13+4+8+20
Out[51]: 45
```